# Mapping JSON to polymorphic POJOs with single- and multi-properties

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I am currently trying to develop a REST client that communicates with a certain online service. This online service returns some JSON responses which I wish to map to Java objects using **Jackson**.

An example of a JSON response would be:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "fields" : [ {
      "type" : "anniversary",
      "value" : {
        "day" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "year" : 1970
      }
    }, {
      "type" : "birthday",
      "value" : {
        "day" : 1,
        "month" : 1,
        "year" : 1970
      }
    }, {
      "type" : "simple",
      "value" : "simple string"
    },{
       "type": "name",
       "value": {
           "firstName": "Joe",
           "lastName": "Brown"
       }
    } ]
}
```

NOTE the following:

- this structure contains a simple id, and a collection of Field instances, each having a *type* and a *value*
- the *value* structure is determined by the external property *type*
- in the example given, there are 3 types -> date, name, and single value string
- the *birthday* and *anniversary* types both match the *date* structure
- there are several types which map to a single value string, like *email* type, *twitterId* type, *company* type etc.

> > My problem is that I do not seem to be able to correctly map this structure to the Java objects

**Here's what I've done so far. The following are the classes and their Jackson annotations**(the getters and setters are omitted).

```
public class Contact {
    private int id;
    private List<Field> fields;
}

public class Field {
    private FieldType type;
    private FieldValue value;
}

public enum FieldType {
    EMAIL, NICKNAME, NAME, ADDRESS, BIRTHDAY, ANNIVERSARY
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type",
        defaultImpl = SingleFieldValue.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NameFieldValue.class, name = "name"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DateFieldValue.class, name = "anniversary"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DateFieldValue.class, name = "birthday"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SingleFieldValue.class, name = "nickname"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SingleFieldValue.class, name = "email"),
        //other types that map to SingleFieldValue
})
public abstract FieldValue {
}


public class NameFieldValue extends FieldValue {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
 }

public class DateFieldValue extends FieldValue {

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
}

public class SingleFieldValue extends FieldValue {

    private String value;
}
```

The **ObjectMapper** does not contain any configuration, the default configuration is used.

What suggestions do you have to correctly map these? I would like to avoid making custom deserializers and just traverse Json objects, like JsonNode.

**NOTE**: I apologize in advance for any lack of information to make this issue clear enough. Please state any problems with my formulation.

Comment: Have you considered simply writing some software to do this?

Comment: My desire is too use Jackson for unmarshalling the JSON. I suppose that's what you are referring to.

Comment: Get `value` as a Map and sort it out.  You can leave the rest.

Comment: Not a very clean solution. I would have to manually access the map with hardcoded strings in order to get the desired values. I would prefer Jackson assign the properties to their proper place, and I would just call get*()

Comment: OK, you try that, and see which takes more time to implement, and which is harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used an abstract class on the FieldValue level to use it in FIeld class. In that case you can construct the object with type=email and value=address which can lead to some issues...

I would recommend to create a specific classes for every type with specific FieldValue type. 
The following code is serializing/deserializing JSON from/to required format from/to POJO:

```
public class Main {
    String json = "{\"id\":1,\"fields\":[{\"type\":\"SIMPLE\",\"value\":\"Simple Value\"},{\"type\":\"NAME\",\"value\":{\"firstName\":\"first name\",\"lastName\":\"last name\"}}]}";

    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(generate());
        System.out.println(json);

        System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue(json, Contact.class));
    }

    private static Contact generate() {
        SimpleField simpleField = SimpleField.builder().type(FieldType.SIMPLE).value("Simple Value").build();

        NameFieldValue nameFieldValue = NameFieldValue.builder().firstName("first name").lastName("last name").build();
        NameField nameField = NameField.builder().type(FieldType.NAME).value(nameFieldValue).build();

        return Contact.builder().id(1).fields(Arrays.asList(simpleField, nameField)).build();
    }
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleField.class, name = "SIMPLE"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = NameField.class, name = "NAME")
})
interface Field {
    FieldType getType();
    Object getValue();
}

enum FieldType {
    SIMPLE, NAME
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Contact {
    private int id;
    private List<Field> fields;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class SimpleField implements Field {
    private FieldType type;
    private String value;

    @Override
    public FieldType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class NameField implements Field {
    private FieldType type;
    private NameFieldValue value;

    @Override
    public FieldType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class NameFieldValue {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

I have used lombok library here just to minimize the code and avoiding creating getters/setters as well as constructors. You can delete lombok annotations and add getters/setters/constructors and code will work the same.

So, the idea is that you have a Contact class (which is root of your JSON) with a list of Fields (where Field is an interface). Every Field type has own implementation like NameField implements Field and has NameFieldValue as a property. The trick here is that you can change getValue() method declaration and declare that it returns the common interface or Object (I used Object but interface will work as well).

This solution doesn't require any custom serializers/deserializers and easy in maintenance.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. But this has indeed helped me reach a solution. With one note that the value for the include, in this case, is now JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, as it is on the same level as the  Field object. Thank you very much!